# How to hide the title of a chapter in KOMA script?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, koma-script, titles

In KOMA-script report, how to hide the title of an unnumbered chapter at the start of the chapter itself, yet show the title of the chapter in the table of contents?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\addchap{CV}

I want to hide the title above.

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE page 1]
[image: MWE page 2]

In this specific example, I want the title of the chapter "CV" not to appear on the second page, where the chapter starts.

Since KOMA script and the `titlesec` package have compatibility issues I need a method without using `titlesec`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CV}

I want to hide the title above.

\end{document}
```